# WordPress Search Queries

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have added within my WordPress 3.1 site, the following code at the bottom of my sidebar.php file:

```
    <div id="search_box">
      <form id="searchform" action="http://www.service.com/" method="get" role="search">
          <input id="s" type="text" name="s" class="search" value="Search site" size="19" maxlength="80" id="white_box" onfocus="if (this.value=='Search site') this.value = ''"/>
          <input id="searchsubmit" type="image" class="submit" value="submit" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/search_btn.jpg" />
      </form>
    </div>
```

As I have coded this search process myself, when I place a some text within my search text box and press the "Search" button, it looks as if, is is calling the page search.php within my theme and displaying the results.

Questions:

1) where/how does it know when I press the "Search" button to go off and call search.php?

2) if possible only, how can I change it to call a different php file instead of the search.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use template filter

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'template_include', 10 );
```

and change the template as

```
function template_include($template)
{

    if(your condition here){
        $template = get_template_directory().'/your-template.php';
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: If this is your right answer you should accept as answer, no ?

Answer (score 0):

-1. All requests for a WP site go to a single page that routes them based upon specific criteria. Thus when a search is performed it knows that it is a search and directs to the search.php page.

Specifically it goes to index.php that loads wp-blog-header.php.

-2: Everything you need to know should be right here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page#Using_the_page.php

Answer (score 0):

1. Wordpress assumes the request is a search if it sees an 's' GET variable.
2. You can hook into the `template_redirect` action (in your theme's `functions.php` file) and load a different template like so:

   ```
   add_action('template_redirect', 'my_template_select');
   function my_template_select() {
     if (is_search()) {
       load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/foobar.php');
       exit;
     } 
   }
   ```

Comment: exiting after load_template() is not good as you might not be able to use hooks after template is loaded.